# How do I access members of a class in C# like I think I could do in c++?

Tags: c#, c++

How do I access members of a class in C# like I think I could do in c++ ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

    namespace DateAndMoney
    {
        class InputNode
        {
            DateTime dateTime;
            string dollarAmount;
        }
        class Program
        {
            public static void ReadFile(string filename)
            {
                InputNode inputNode = new InputNode();
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filename));

                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var input = reader.ReadLine();
                        var values = input.Split(',');
                        inputNode.dateTime = values[0];
                        inputNode.dollarAmount = values[1];

                    }
                }
            }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string filename;
                Console.WriteLine("enter path and file name of input file");
                filename = Console.ReadLine();
                ReadFile(filename);
            }
        }
    }
```

The precompiler does not like:

```
            inputNode.dateTime = values[0];
            inputNode.dollarAmount = values[1];
```

And this change changes nothing

```
struct InputNode
{
    DateTime dateTime;
    string dollarAmount;
}
```

Comment: You need to make them public if you wish to see them outside the class

Comment: Before you take your values out of your `values` list, you'll have to cast or parse them to the right type

Answer (score 0):

You could create public method, which returns the value of a particular member (recommended) or make the members themselves public.
You can use for reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx)

```
class InputNode
{
   private DateTime dateTime;
   private string dollarAmount;

   public DateTime GetDate()
   {
         return dateTime;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
class InputNode
{
   DateTime dateTime;
   string dollarAmount;
}
```

to

```
class InputNode
{
   public DateTime dateTime;
   public string dollarAmount;
}
```

You can then access them as you were trying, although you'd need to convert your text to date to put it in the date time.

Answer (score 0):

By default in C# fields are private, so you can't access it. Better to use [Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) to set and get values

In your case:

```
class InputNode
    {
       public DateTime DateTime{get;set;}
       public string DollarAmount{get;set}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace DateAndMoney
{
    public class InputNode
    {
        public DateTime dateTime;
        public string dollarAmount;
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            InputNode inputNode = new InputNode();
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filename));

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var input = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = input.Split(',');
                    try
                    {
                        inputNode.dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(values[0]);
                        inputNode.dollarAmount = Convert.ToDouble(values[1]);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {}
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename;
            Console.WriteLine("enter path and file name of input file");
            filename = Console.ReadLine();
            ReadFile(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but I prefer using  public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

This did it.

```
 class InputNode
    {
        public DateTime dateTime;
        public string dollarAmount;
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static void ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            InputNode inputNode = new InputNode();
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filename));

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var input = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = input.Split(',');
                    inputNode.dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(values[0]);
                    inputNode.dollarAmount = values[1];

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: when converting to date time, consider using the format in the conversion for readability, like this:  DateTime.ParseExact(values[0], "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)

Answer (score 0):

First of all ( as everyone else said ) you need to make the fields "visible" for the rest of the application.

```
class InputNode
{
    // DateTime dateTime;
    internal DateTime dateTime;
    public string dollarAmount;
    // string dollarAmount;
}
```

You can read more about [access modifiers here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

Second thing is that you're assigning `string` to the `DateTime` type field. In C# you have bunch of **converters** which can cast from one type into another and also you can create your own converters using [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx)